# Java - <identifier> expecter error

Tags: java, compiler-construction, identifier

I was writing a java tool that toggles wether a game mod is active (specifically, the game is Dwarf Fortress, and the mod is DFHack) and the program is nearly done. However, I cant seem to get the variables right that tell the program how to check if the mod is active or not.
I got this status file containing a single character, being 1 for active and 0 for inactive.
This is the code (By the way, if it is needed: I checked the name of the file and it matches the class declaration).

```
package nl.dirkkok.dfhacktoggle;

/* 
 * DFHacktoggle
 * 28-12-2013 @ 2:02 PM
 * 
 * This program will disable DFHack if it is enabled, and enable it if it is disabled.
 *
 * Using this tool is at your own risk. If you send me an email complaining about this program doing anything you dont want, then I will laugh at you, and tell you that you cant read. :)
 * 
 * Created by Dirk Kok <d.kok.2000@gmail.com>. This tool is my property, but I do not claim rights of neither Dwarf Fortress nor DFHack.
 */

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.IOException;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;

public class Dfhacktoggle {
    private static Path statusfile = "dfhack-status";
    private boolean dfhack = false;
    private byte[] fileArray = new byte[1];
    private byte[] active = new byte[1];
    private byte[] inactive = new byte[1];
    private file dfhacksdl = "SDLdfhack.dll";
    private file vanillasdl = "SDLreal.dll";
    private file sdl = "SDL.dll";

    active[] <byte> = 1;
    inactive[] <byte> = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            fileArray = Files.readAllBytes(file);
            if (fileArray[0] == 1) {
                p("DFHack is active. Deactivating...");
                try {
                    if (vanillasdl.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("File exists");
                    sdl.renameTo(dfhacksdl);
                    vanillasdl.renameTo(sdl);
                    Files.write(statusfile, inactive, WRITE);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    errp("DFHack could not be deactivated. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
                    errp("Detailed info:");
                    errp("IOException: " + x);
                } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
                    errp("Status file could not be found. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
                    errp("Detailed info:");
                    errp("NoSuchFileException: " + x);
                }
            } else if (fileArray[0] == 0) {
                p("DFHack is inactive. Activating...");
                try {
                    if(vanillasdl.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("File exists");
                    sdl.renameTo(vanillasdl);
                    dfhacksdl.renameTo(sdl);
                    Files.write(statusfile, active, WRITE);
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    errp("Status could not be checked. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
                    errp("Detailed info:");
                    errp("IOException: " + x);
                } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
                    errp("Status file could not be found. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
                    errp("Detailed info:");
                    errp("NoSuchFileException: " + x);
                }
            } else {
                errp("DFHack's status could not be checked. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            errp("Status could not be checked. Reinstalling the program will solve this.");
            errp("Detailed info:");
            errp(x);
        }
    }

    public void p(String txt) {
        System.out.println(txt);
    }

    public void errp(String txt) {
        System.err.println(txt);
    }
}
```

The compiler returns this:

```
F:\Dfhack-swap>javac Dfhacktoggle.java

Dfhacktoggle:29: error: <identifier> expected
active[] <byte> = 1;
               ^

Dfhacktoggle:30: error: <identifier> expected
inactive[] <byte> = 0;
                 ^
```

Comment: Does `active[] <byte>` look like any Java syntax you've seen before?

Comment: Tried removing <byte>, but that gives the same error. I supposed that <identifier> meant a primitive type in <> brackets.

Comment: @latias1290: I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some Java tutorials so you can get up to speed with the basic syntax. Meanwhile, Tarek has shown you how to set the value in the one-entry `byte` arrays you're creating.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong there's no `active[] <byte> = 1;` in Java

If you want to assign it a value You can do it in this way

```
active[0] = 1;
inactive[0] = 0;
```

But there's no need for array to use it as a boolean you can just define it as a byte

```
byte active= 1;
byte inactive= 0;
```

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that they were declared above.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that a one-entry `byte` array is usually a bit silly. Probably just wants a byte, e.g. the declaration `byte active;` and the assignment `active = 1;` (or of course, combine decl. and init: `byte active = 1;`).

Comment: Tried it, and it gives 8 errors:
Dfhacktoggle.java:29: error: ']' expected
        active[0] = 1;
               ^
Dfhacktoggle.java:29: error: ';' expected
        active[0] = 1;
                ^
Dfhacktoggle.java:29: error: illegal start of type
        active[0] = 1;
                  ^
Dfhacktoggle.java:29: error: <identifier> expected
        active[0] = 1;
And the same ones for the inactive variable

Comment: Also, I need to use arrays because otherwise `Files.write()` generates a ton of errors

Comment: @latias1290: You also have to move the lines into a method (`main`, for instance). But you also have the problem that you're declaring instance members, but not creating an instance, so for example access to `fileArray` will fail with an error about accessing non-static members from a static context. Again: Step back and work through some basic Java tutorials, the code as shown is riddled with fundamental issues that tutorials will help you understand and correct.